# Queues and Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue

What is the best `Queue` Data structure to use in C# when the Queue needs to be accsible for `Enqueue()` on multiple threads but only needs to `Dequeue()` on a single main thread? My thread structure looks like this:

> - Main Thread - Consumer
> - Sub Thread1 - Producer
> - Sub Thread2 - Producer
> - Sub Thread3 - Producer

I have a single `Queue<T> queue` that holds all items produced by the sub-threads and the Main Thread calls `queue.Dequeue()` until it is empty. I have the following function that is called on my Main Thread for this purpose.

```
public void ConsumeItems()
{
    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
         var item = queue.Dequeue();
         ...
    }
}
```

The Main Thread calls this function once through each thread loop and I want to make sure I am accessing `queue` in a thread-safe manor but I also want to avoid locking `queue` if possible for performance reasons.

Comment: Assume you'll want something from [system.collections.concurrent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I would avoid explicit queue management and take a look at the TPL Dataflow library instead.

Answer (score 1):

The one you would want to use is a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) which by default is backed by a [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx). To get items out of the queue you would use `.GetConsumingEnumerable()` from inside a foreach

```
public BlockingCollection<Item> queue = new BlockingCollection<Item>();

public void LoadItems()
{
    var(var item in SomeDataSource())
    {
         queue.Add(item);
    }
    queue.CompleteAdding();
}

public void ConsumeItems()
{
    foreach(var item in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

When the queue is empty the foreach will block the thread and unblock as soon as a item becomes available. once `.CompleteAdding()` has been called the foreach will finish processing any items in the queue but once it is empty it will exit the foreach block.

However, before you do this, I would recommend you look in to [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx), with it you don't need to manage the queues or the threads anymore. It lets you build chains of logic and each block in the chain can have a separate level of concurrency.

```
public Task ProcessDataAsync(IEnumerable<SomeInput> input)
{
    using(var outfile = new File.OpenWrite("outfile.txt"))
    {
        //Create a convert action that uses the number of processors on the machine to create parallel blocks for processing.
        var convertBlock = new TransformBlock<SomeInput, string>(x => CpuIntensiveConversion(x), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Enviorment.ProcessorCount});

        //Create a single threaded action that writes out to the textwriter.
        var writeBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(x => outfile.WriteLine(x))

        //Link the convert block to the write block.
        convertBlock.LinkTo(writeBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions{PropagateCompletion = true});

        //Add items to the convert block's queue.
        foreach(var item in input)
        {
              await convertBlock.SendAsync();
        }

        //Tell the convert block we are done adding. This will tell the write block it is done processing once all items are processed.
        convertBlock.Complete();

        //Wait for the write to finish writing out to the file;
        await writeBlock.Completion;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops I wrote my examples backward. One producer, many consumers. The solution does not change, just the examples need to.